# Jasmine SpyOn on $window.print is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a one test case which aims to check whether $window.print() is calling or not?

For that i have a written a following test case:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($window) {

        Objwindow = $window;
}
it('Test for print', function() {
    spyOn( Objwindow, 'print' ).and.callFake( function() {
        console.log("Spy is called");
        return true;
    });
    scope.printConfirmation();
    expect(Objwindow.print).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

In Controller:

```
scope.printConfirmation = function() {
    $window.print()
}
```

Now, If i run the above only testcase , It is running successfully without any errors. i.e.. Spyon is getting called.
But if i run the test cases of all modules(almost there are 1325 test cases), it is throwing the following error.

```
 Expected spy print to have been called.
```

What might be the cause for this issue? Am i doing any thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have to take the instance of controller

like `var controller = $controller('Controller', { $window: Objwindow });`

and your test case should be inside it

```
it('Test for print', function() {
spyOn( Objwindow, 'print' ).and.callFake( function() {
    console.log("Spy is called");
    return true;
scope.printConfirmation();
expect(Objwindow.print).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```